# Программирование на C# помогите найти проблему

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio, button, ui

написал код и задал ему значение что после того как игрок коснется тега finish он перейдет в меню с уровнями и там должен открыться новый уровень. персонаж переходит и в прочем все отлично но уровни также не открываются помогите исправить.

код №1

```
public static int countUnlockedLevel = 1;

[SerializeField]
Sprite unlockedIcon;

[SerializeField]
Sprite lockedIcon;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        #region RenameButtonsAndChangeText
        int numLvl = i + 1;
        transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.name = numLvl.ToString();
        transform.GetChild(i).transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = numLvl.ToString();
        #endregion

        if (i < countUnlockedLevel)
        {
            #region FirstStateBtn
            transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = unlockedIcon;
            transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
            #endregion
        }
        else
        {
            #region SndStateBtn
            transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = lockedIcon;
            transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
            #endregion
        }
    }   
}
```

код №2

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update(Collider2D shit)
{
    if (shit.gameObject.tag == "finish") {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex == LevelManager.countUnlockedLevel)
        {
            LevelManager.countUnlockedLevel ++;
        }
        Debug.Log("YOU WIN!!!");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это у вас unity?

Comment: Да это юнити перепробовал много скриптов и ни один не работет незнаю что делать

Comment: Добавьте тег `unity3d` к вопросу

Comment: добавил теперь ждать?