# Программирование на C# не могу найти ошибку в коде

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio, button, ui

написал код и задал ему значение что после того как игрок коснется тега finish он перейдет в меню с уровнями и там должен открыться новый уровень. персонаж переходит и в прочем все отлично но уровни также не открываются помогите исправить. Я думаю что ошибка в коде.

код №1

```
public static int countUnlockedLevel = 1;

[SerializeField]
Sprite unlockedIcon;

[SerializeField]
Sprite lockedIcon;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        #region RenameButtonsAndChangeText
        int numLvl = i + 1;
        transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.name = numLvl.ToString();
        transform.GetChild(i).transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = numLvl.ToString();
        #endregion

        if (i < countUnlockedLevel)
        {
            #region FirstStateBtn
            transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = unlockedIcon;
            transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
            #endregion
        }
        else
        {
            #region SndStateBtn
            transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = lockedIcon;
            transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
            #endregion
        }
    }   
}
```

код №2

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update(Collider2D shit)
{
    if (shit.gameObject.tag == "finish") {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex == LevelManager.countUnlockedLevel)
        {
            LevelManager.countUnlockedLevel ++;
        }
        Debug.Log("YOU WIN!!!");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Еще раз 8 спросите - вам обязательно ответят на 10й раз.

Comment: Возможно [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1134974/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Программирование на C# помогите найти проблему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1134974/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83)